# How to parse google Trends HTML page in JAVA

Tags: html, html-parsing

http://www.google.co.in/trends/?q=+indian+Rs

is the link.

Can any body help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jericho HTML parser you can download it from this link it is much better then DOM parser and SAX parser http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/Jericho-HTML-Parser.shtml Try to search some tutorials you find will find lots of tutorials on this.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't offer an official API to access Google Trends, but there are several unofficial APIs floating around on the web.

This Python implementation on GitHub for example: https://github.com/suryasev/unofficial-google-trends-api